# Mysql dump code using perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I want to do the mysql-dump using perl script.Backup from some tables from mysql database in perl script.

```
system(mysqldump -u username -pPassword databasename database table > to /local path) or die..;
```

Tell me this line which will store backup file of tables to the local path.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: I want exact backup line

Comment: You have all needed resources to resolve your own problem.

Comment: Hopefully you know your user name, password and local file system?

Comment: *“I want”* won't get you the help you're after. But some politeness and manners, and showing that you've put some effort into finding the solution yourself just might

Comment: @Uwe Allner Ya I know the username and password..but the line which I have written that line gives me syntax error\. so, I want the perfect line to do mysqldump of tables in perl script.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running that line from the command prompt?  It looks like it should work.  Are you putting the command in quotes?

system('mysqldump -u username -pPassword databasename database table > to /local path') or die('This failed');